# SQL Statement - SQL Matrix

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

For the following Table, is it possible, to create an SQL Statement to create a data Matrix or view?

**Table:**

```
TeamA|TeamB|Won|Lost
--------------------
  A  |  B  | 5 | 3
  A  |  C  | 2 | 4
  A  |  D  | 9 | 1
  B  |  E  | 5 | 5
  C  |  A  | 2 | 4
```

**Result-Matrix:**

```
     |  A | B |  C | D | E
----------------------------
  A  |  0 | 2 | -2 | 8 | 0
  B  |  0 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0
  C  | -2 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0
```

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to do it for the specific case of five teams, but a generic solution that would scale to any number of teams and games would be quite tricky using sql alone.

Comment: Databases are there to hold and get the data, **not** to format it nicely. That's done in presentation layer!

Comment: @Megachip . . . both of these are matrixes.  They are just represented differently.

Comment: @tombom, i know, but the question is, is it possible (and which sql statement will generate it), not is is useful or recommended.

Comment: @Gordon, right, i'm sorry. Not my native language

Comment: @Megachip Is it possible? Sure, why not. Will I put work into it? Definitely not.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: @bluefeet, atm MySQL, but would be nice, if it is a general sql statemant, no MySQL specific functions (if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that you can *pivot* data in MySQL. If you know the values ahead of time (teams) then you will hard-code the values or you can use a prepared statement to generate dynamic sql.

A static version would be:

```
select TeamA,
  max(case when TeamB = 'A' then won - lost else 0 end) as A,
  max(case when TeamB = 'B' then won - lost else 0 end) as B,
  max(case when TeamB = 'C' then won - lost else 0 end) as C,
  max(case when TeamB = 'D' then won - lost else 0 end) as D,
  max(case when TeamB = 'E' then won - lost else 0 end) as E
from yourtable
group by TeamA;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e02c/2)

If you want to use a dynamic version with a prepared statement, the code would be:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN TeamB = ''',
      TeamB,
      ''' THEN won - lost else 0 END) AS `',
      TeamB, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from
(
  select *
  from yourtable
  order by teamb
) x;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT TeamA, ', @sql, ' 
           from yourtable
           group by TeamA');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bb19/12).

Edit #1, after thinking about this I would actually do this a slight bit different. I would generate a true matrix os the data where the teams appeared in both the row and the column. To do this you would first use a `UNION ALL` query to get all teams in two columns:

```
select teama Team1, teamb Team2,
  won-lost Total
from yourtable
union all
select teamb, teama,
  won-lost
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e02c/13). Once that is done, then you would *pivot* the data:

```
select Team1,
  coalesce(max(case when Team2 = 'A' then Total end), 0) as A,
  coalesce(max(case when Team2 = 'B' then Total end), 0) as B,
  coalesce(max(case when Team2 = 'C' then Total end), 0) as C,
  coalesce(max(case when Team2 = 'D' then Total end), 0) as D,
  coalesce(max(case when Team2 = 'E' then Total end), 0) as E
from
(
  select teama Team1, teamb Team2,
    won-lost Total
  from yourtable
  union all
  select teamb, teama,
    won-lost
  from yourtable
) src
group by Team1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e02c/19). Which gives a more detailed result of:

```
| TEAM1 |  A | B |  C | D | E |
-------------------------------
|     A |  0 | 2 | -2 | 8 | 0 |
|     B |  2 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0 |
|     C | -2 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0 |
|     D |  8 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0 |
|     E |  0 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0 |
```

Comment: @Megachip can you edit the sql fiddle with a sample of the data? Then post the link as a comment.

Comment: @Megachip the problem is the limit of the `group_concat` length.  You will have to expand it (See the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)). Here is a working fiddle -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40bb3/6

Comment: THX a lot. I think that solves my problem. Except this is a mysql specific solution, it is an solution in SQL ;)

Comment: @Megachip the static version can be used on any database. For a dynamic solution it would have to be database specific, each one has their one syntax.

Comment: @Megachip I made a slight adjustment to my answer and included a way to produce a more detailed result with all teams appearing as both a row and a column.

Comment: THX again, helpful in general, in my case, team A is not 100% identical with team A ;) But i've got another problem: How can i join the header with a second table? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e22e/2

Comment: @Megachip you should post a new question with that request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780016/prepared-statement-how-to-join-header

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a SQL statement or view that has a variable number of columns.  In standard SQL, you can pivot the data by doing something like:

```
select TeamA,
       max(case when TeamB = 'A' then won - lost end) as A,
       max(case when TeamB = 'B' then won - lost end) as B,
       max(case when TeamB = 'C' then won - lost end) as C,
       max(case when TeamB = 'D' then won - lost end) as D,
       max(case when TeamB = 'E' then won - lost end) as E
from t
group by TeamA
order by 1
```

Some databases support a pivot statement.

To do this generically, you would have to create a SQL statement as a string, and then execute it (often called *dynamic* SQL).  Such a statement could be produced by SQL, by a stored procedure, in Excel, or some other programming tool.  It then would need to be executed.

Let me repeat:  any given SQL statement has a pre-defined set of columns.  You cannot vary the number of columns.

Comment: OK, thats a specific one... is it possible to do some loops? Or is a generic statement definitive impossible?

Comment: It's not a case to loop through data in SQL. Use another level (C#, php or another language which you are using).

Comment: @RomanBadiornyi, as said in question, its a technical question, not a "usage question"