# SQL - How can I achieve a matrix?

Tags: sql-server, matrix

I'm relatively new to SQL and have impressed myself just getting to the output below.

The 'HomeTeamSequence' and 'AwayTeamSequence' columns are the last two results for the home team and away team respectively. 'FTR' is the actual result of that particular match.

```
   with games as (

   SELECT t.Div, t.Date, t.HomeTeam, t.AwayTeam, t.FTHG, t.FTAG, t.FTR, 
   t.MatchID, U.team_id
   FROM All_Games.[dbo].[All_Games_Full] t 
   cross apply (values(HomeTeam), (AwayTeam)) as u(team_id)

    ), 

    games_update as (

    select *, 
    case when HomeTeam = team_id and FTR = 'H' then 'HW'
         WHEN HomeTeam = team_id and FTR = 'D' then 'HD'
         WHEN HomeTeam = team_id and FTR = 'A' then 'HL'
         when AwayTeam = team_id and FTR = 'A' then 'AW'
         WHEN AwayTeam = team_id and FTR = 'D' then 'AD'
         WHEN AwayTeam = team_id and FTR = 'H' then 'AL'
         ELSE NULL END NewFTR
    from games

    ), seq as (

    select MatchID, Div, Date, team_id,
    concat(case when LAG(team_id,2) over (order by team_id, Date) != team_id then null else LAG(NewFTR, 2) OVER (ORDER BY team_id, Date) end, ' ' ,
    case when LAG(team_id,1) over (order by team_id, Date) != team_id then null else LAG(NewFTR, 1) OVER (ORDER BY team_id, Date) end) as lastgame,
    NewFTR AS latestgame
    from games_update

    )

    select a.MatchID, a.Div, a.Date, a.HomeTeam, a.AwayTeam,
    case when a.HomeTeam = b.team_id then b.lastgame end HomeTeamSequence,
    case when a.AwayTeam = c.team_id then c.lastgame end AwayTeamSequence, 
    a.FTR
    from All_Games.[dbo].[All_Games_Full] a
    left join  seq b
    on a.MatchID = b.MatchID and a.HomeTeam = b.team_id
    left join seq c
    on a.MatchID = c.MatchID and a.AwayTeam = c.team_id
    where a.Div = 'SP1'
    ORDER BY MatchID
```

sample output:

```
MatchID Div    Date     HomeTeam    AwayTeam   HomeTeamSequence    AwayTeamSequence    FTR
135038  SP1 1995-10-01  La Coruna   Albacete    HW AD              AL HW        H
135039  SP1 1995-10-01  Merida      Salamanca   HL AL              AL HD        D
135040  SP1 1995-10-01  Oviedo      Betis       AW HD              AW HD        A
135041  SP1 1995-10-01  Sevilla     Ath Madrid  HW AD              AW HW        D
135042  SP1 1995-10-01  Valladolid  Tenerife    HD AD              AD HD        H
135043  SP1 1995-10-01  Vallecano   Valencia    HL AL              AW HD        H
135044  SP1 1995-10-01  Zaragoza    Compostela  HL AD              AD HW        H
135045  SP1 1995-10-04  Albacete    Valladolid  HW AL              AD HW        H
135046  SP1 1995-10-04  Barcelona   Oviedo      HW AD              HD HL        H
```

What i'm trying to achieve is the following matrix (just a sample of the header/row combinations). Just focusing on 'FTR' = 'H':

```
      AD AD    AD AL   AD AW   AD HD   AD HL
AD AD   0       0       0       0       0
AD AL   0       0       0       0       0
AD AW   0       0       0       0       0
AD HD   3       0       1       1       1
AD HL   1       2       3       2       2
AD HW   1       3       3       1       1
AL AD   0       0       0       0       0
AL AL   0       0       0       0       0
```

i've added the following to the above query to test a few combos but it's not looking close.

```
    select
    case when HomeTeamSequence = 'HW HW' THEN COUNT(*) else 0 END 'HW HW',
    case when HomeTeamSequence = 'HW HD' THEN COUNT(*) else 0 END 'HW HD',
    case when HomeTeamSequence = 'HW HL' THEN COUNT(*) else 0 END 'HW HL',
    case when HomeTeamSequence = 'HW AW' THEN COUNT(*) else 0 END 'HW AW',
    case when HomeTeamSequence = 'HW AD' THEN COUNT(*) else 0 END 'HW AD',
    case when HomeTeamSequence = 'HW AL' THEN COUNT(*) else 0 END 'HW AL'
    from fixture_list
    WHERE ftr = 'H'
    GROUP BY HomeTeamSequence
```

I'm assuming I need to have some sort of pivot in there.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: sorry, wrong tag. SQL server

Comment: Using `GROUP BY` on `HomeTeamSequence` and having it on your `CASE` expression doesn't make sense. One of them needs to change to `AwayTeamSequence` (I assume the `CASE`).

Comment: sample data of tables would be very helpful.

Comment: if problem is still not solve then I suggest you to explain the question. Just post sample data and output expected with explanation. You are missing explanation of your output

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding the following to the initial query:

```
    select Team1,
    coalesce(max(case when Team2 = 'HW HW' then Total end), 0) as 'HW HW',
    coalesce(max(case when Team2 = 'HW HD' then Total end), 0) as 'HW HD',
    coalesce(max(case when Team2 = 'HW HL' then Total end), 0) as 'HW HL'
    --creates row headers
    --repeat for other combinations
    from
    (
    select AwayTeamSequence Team1, HomeTeamSequence Team2,
    COUNT(*) as Total
    from fixture_list
    where FTR = 'H'
    group by HomeTeamSequence, AwayTeamSequence
    ) src
    group by Team1;
```

the following link helped me get this answer: [SQL Statement - SQL Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772882/sql-statement-sql-matrix)